# dlmenu scroll does not allow access for last few elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm using the [Hipstr Jekyll theme](https://github.com/mmistakes/hpstr-jekyll-theme) which makes use of the jQuery plugin [dlmenu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/), a responsive menu.

[Hipstr's about page](https://mmistakes.github.io/hpstr-jekyll-theme/theme-setup/) suffers from the scrollbar not appearing at all. So a slightly different problem, but neither of us got it to work right. There is an [issue on Hipstr here](https://github.com/mmistakes/hpstr-jekyll-theme/issues/14).

The structure is `nav > ul > li > ul`. When I'm in the sub-submenu, the scroll bar won't reach the last elements. This is some sort of issue related to height and overflow, and I have yet to chase which container is causing the problem.

[image]

I'm also trying to make sure I find a solution that doesn't hardcode pixels in a way that couples it to a screen size.

What's causing the scroll not to go down further?

Comment: Mind providing an example?

Comment: @JoshCrozier I'm not sure what you mean, I can't exactly post thousands of lines of code, and if I could find a minimum reproducible example I wouldn't need to ask the question, since my problem is that I can't isolate what's causing the problem. I provided a screenshot, and added a red circle around where the scroll bar would be if I hovered over it.

Comment: Alright -- I'll check out the demos you linked to then.

Comment: @JoshCrozier https://mmistakes.github.io/hpstr-jekyll-theme/theme-setup/ actually the main hipstr theme site has this problem, although I guess no scroll bar at all. neither of us got it to work right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem - or more precisely, source of confusion - is roughly the fact that the outer `nav` element only contains children with absolute position. Therefore it has no height of its own. If you set overflow = scroll, for instance, you will now have a 0px tall `nav` element over which you may scroll stuff.

The most basic hack would be to blow up the height of the `nav`, then use the more familiar max-height and overflow properties as expected. This SCSS seems to work:

```
nav#dl-menu {
    @media #{$medium} {
        // The children of this element are absolute, so
        // this has no height of its own. Must prop up
        // before enable overflow:scroll. This is probably
        // still a kludge.
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 90%;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
}
```